# nginx how to replace try_files with proxy_pass having multiple paths

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I have a set of rules in Nginx of this type:

```
location ~ ^/race/[a-z0-9\-_]*/session/[a-z0-9\-]*/topic/[a-z0-9\-_]*$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /race/period/session/team/topic/index.html;
}

location /images/assets/ {
   try_files /backup/data$uri /default_images/small_asset.png =404;
}
```

These rules work when the files exist on the server but now the data is in a remote location (AWS - S3+cloudfront) I  need to use `proxy_pass`, but wondering how to deal with cases when I have multiple choices like:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /race/period/session/team/topic/index.html;
```

And

```
try_files /backup/data$uri /default_images/small_asset.png =404;
```

How to handle the first path in a remove endpoint for example:

```
location /images/assets/ {
   proxy_pass http://abc.cloudfront.net/backup/data 
   # but if I get a 404 here,how to fall back to: 
   proxy_pass http://abc.cloudfront.net/default_images/small_assets.png
}
```

Any ideas? not necessary I need to use Nginx now that the content is hosted remotely, open to any alternatives.

Comment: To fallback on 404 you would need to use `error_page`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page).

Comment: any idea how to also deal with the regex when using proxy_pass?